# Subsets and shapeless extensible records

Tags: scala, record, shapeless

How to define polymorphic function which:

1. accept any record containing specified set of fields (superset of fields)
2. return any subset of specified set of fields
   with shapeless-2.3?

I've found [solution for single field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19316446/2236092) for 1. but I need to work with a set of fields. I've found [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20315002/2236092) to define class containing implicits for each of the field, but I think it should be less boilerplated way to define it in such advanced language like Scala. I've found an [assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35702275/2236092) than `SelectAll` trait can be used for that but not concrete example how exactly it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question is the duplicate of this one:

[Checking for subtype relationship between extensible records in shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803930/checking-for-subtype-relationship-between-extensible-records-in-shapeless?answertab=votes#tab-top)

The functionality you look for is implemented as **Extractor** typeclass and will be present in shapeless 2.3.3 (github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/714)